# Get what stage of a pipeline failed in post actions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my pipeline's `post{falure{}}` block I want to report at which stage the pipeline failed. Is there an env or something that tracks this?

Answer (score 0):

Using a try/catch block you could store the failed stage name in a list and use this in the post to report failed stage names